# Visual Studio 2019 Autocomplete on Tab

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there an extension for Visual Studio 2019 that will autocomplete HTML CSS classes?  I used to have this but can't remember what extension it was.

In Visual Studio,  I would type ".row",  press the tab key and it would convert ".row" into

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

likewise, I could type ".col", press tab and it would convert ".col" into

```
<div class="col"></div>
```

I got it working after installing the Emmet.net plugin from the VSIX Gallery but oddly, it only works if I open the code snippet manager in VS then close it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ZenCode extension, it supports Visual Studio 2019 and 2017.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding